# MongoDB update :- update multiple objects nested inside array (in multiple documents)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My collection is as follows :

```
{
  "_id" : "",
  "team" : "avenger",
  "persons" : [
    {
      "name" : "ABC",
      "class" : "10",
      "is_new" :  true
    },
    {
      "name" : "JHK",
      "class" : "12",
      "is_new" :  true
    },
    {
      "name" : "BNH",
      "class" : "10",
      "is_new" :  true
    }
  ]
},
{
  "_id" : "",
  "team" : "adrenaline",
  "persons" : [
    {
      "name" : "HTU",
      "class" : "11",
      "is_new" :  true
    },
    {
      "name" : "NVG",
      "class" : "10",
      "is_new" :  true
    },
    {
      "name" : "SED",
      "class" : "8",
      "is_new" :  true
    }
  ]
}
```

My Goal is to find for all such documents which contain such nested objects in "persons" where "class" is "10" and update "is_new" field to "false"

I am using mongoose update with "multi" set to true

Query :

```
{                
  persons: { $elemMatch: { class: "10" } }
}
```

Options:

```
{
  multi : true
}
```

Update :

First one I have tried is :

```
{
  $set : {
    "persons.$.is_new" : false
  }
}
```

Second one is :

```
{
  $set : {
    "persons.$[].is_new" : false
  }
}
```

The issue is : using **$ in update operation updates only first match in the "persons" array** for all matched documents.

If I use **$[], it updates all the objects of "persons" array in the matched documents**.

Workaround can be to use a loop for update operation but i believe that should not be the ideal case.

I see nothing in the docs, though have found people reporting this update operation issue.

Is this can't be done using a single query ?? **Is looping through documents my only option ?**

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the filtered positional operator [**`$[<identifier>]`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) identifier

```
Model.update(
  { "persons": { "$elemMatch": { "class": "10" }}},
  { "$set" : { "persons.$[e].is_new" : false }},
  { "arrayFilters": [{ "e.class": "10" }], "multi" : true }
)
```